# Error while compiling modified cmd_vel_mux

Tags: ros, amcl-pose, nodelet-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am using **ROS fuerte version** and the simulator is USARSim. I use the ** velocity multiplexer (sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-yujin-ocs)** designed by YujinRobot(http://wiki.ros.org/cmd_vel_mux).

I modify the one header file and one cpp file, to incorporate one more subscriber (so that nodelet manager subscribes to amcl_pose topic). But when I compile the code following error appears.

**make output**
[image: image description]

**NOW ABOVE ERROR IS SOLVED BY FOLLOWING THE ANSWER**

**Problem OCCURS When I run FOLLOWING COMMAND**

**roslaunch cmd_vel_mux standalone.launch**

http://pastebin.com/XnUkXRCZ

***nodelet_manager and velocity_multiplexer nodes  don't get initialized***

You can **view the highlighted portion of the header** file here
http://pastebin.com/0aJzRS2x

***Please help..LOOK in the above TWO LINKS***

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/157661/error-while-compiling-modified-cmd_vel_mux/) by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2014-04-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2014-07-07**:
As an aside, logging in as root and performing operations is not considered good practice. Everything you need can be accomplished using the 'normal' user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suspect that you forgot to add

```
#include <geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped.h>
```

in  `cmd_vel_mux_nodelet.h`.

I´d recommend posting code directly or a link to it, as opposed to taking screenshots of it (as screenshots don´t allow copy/pasting code, eat bandwidth and are generally unwieldy)

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2014-04-26**:
Oh, thanks a lot. Now, there is no error while 'make'. But when I try to launch nodelet_manager, some error appears as updated in the question..

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-04-26**:
If a new error appears after solving the first problem, please do not exchange the original question. Any answers won't match any more and anyone that finds this problem later won't be helped. Open a new question for a new problem instead.

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2014-04-26**:
Now I use pastebin @Stefan Kohlbrecher. I have changed the question accordingly @dornhege.

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2014-04-26**:
Why we can't add our own function? Added a new question, please have a look http://answers.ros.org/question/157886/error-while-loading-nodelet-velocity_multiplexer/